# Смена цвета BorderBrush у ComboBox по нажатию кнопки. C# WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

Есть comboBox и кнопка, Если мы нажимаем на кнопку и в comboBox ничего не выбрано, SelectItem == null, то надо изменить цвет BorderBrush данного comboBox-а

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            KeyValuePair<int, string> SelectedItem = (KeyValuePair<int, string>)comboBox.SelectedItem;
            foreach (Window window in App.Current.Windows)
            {
                if (window is MainWindow)
                    window.Title = "HackVision - Cam: " + SelectedItem.Value;
            }
            var second = new ViewDeviceWebcam(mainWindow);
            second.Show();
            second.Close();
            mainWindow.StartMethodFrame(SelectedItem);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

Код из xaml файла:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,54,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="390" Cursor="Hand"/>
```

Comment: Используйте MVVM и валидацию

Comment: а Binding не поможет? Или это оно и есть

Comment: Это оно и есть, только правильный способ использования